# Is it possible to use delegates to execute global methods in another Application domain ?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, applicationdomain

I am trying to use delegates to execute methods in another domain, but i can't achieve it , so i want to make sure if it's really possible to do what i am trying to do.
Is it possible to use delegates to execute global methods in another Application domain ?

Comment: Post some code of what you're talking about. We can't imagine what you tried and where you struck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible, The common language runtime does not support serialization of global methods, so delegates cannot be used to execute global methods in other application domains.